# How to Invert a Polar Lemniscata into a hyperbola

Tags: geometry, inverse, python

Hello i want invert a lemniscate but i find few information on internet, i know how to find the inverse of a function in rectangular coordinates functions but i dont know how to do it in polar coordiantes and [how inverting a lemniscate become a hyperbola](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Lemniskate_hyperbel.svg/420px-Lemniskate_hyperbel.svg.png)?.

i am using python for plot because is an assigment.
this is the equation:

r = (a**2)*(np.cos(2*rad))

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math 
  
plt.axes(projection = 'polar') 
a=3
rads = np.arange(0, (2 * np.pi), 0.01) 

for rad in rads: 
    r = (a**2)*(np.cos(2*rad))  
    plt.polar(rad,r,'g.')  
plt.show()
```

[grafica python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCzwC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of MacLaurin polar curves obtained by inversion $ r\to \dfrac{a^2}{r}$

$$ r^n = a^n \cos n \theta, r^n = a^n \sec n \theta $$

In the particular case $n=2$ Lemniscate of Bernoulli and rectangular hyperbola are mutually invertible about radius of inversion circle $r=a=1$

```
 PolarPlot[ {1,Sqrt[Sec[2 t]],Sqrt[Cos[2 t]]},{t,0,2 Pi},PolarGridLines->Automatic]
```

An inversion  transformation between Cartesian coordinates can be written

$$ (x,y)\to \dfrac{a^2\;(x,y)}{x^2+y^2}$$

For $n=1,3$ and inversions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: how do you do the inversion and obtain the hyperbolic?. i am trying and nothing. i have to convert to rectangular?

Comment: An update is given in edit.